# Creating dropdown select menu and passing selected value to controller method in thymeleaf, spring

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am really green when it comes to creating web apps and I got stucked.

So after the user log in to my app my aim is to created dropdown menu with all users i have in my db.
 Here is how i put it in select menu:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginWeb", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginWeb(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
model.addAttribute("users", repository.findAll());
return "loginWeb"; }
```

my loginWeb template looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Choose employee</p>
<form th:action="@{/getDetailsWeb}" method="post">
    <select name="idUser">
        <option th:each="user : ${users}"
                th:value="${user.idUser}"
                th:text="${user.lastName}"/>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" title="Submit">Get details</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the dropdown menu is filled with surnames of users. The problem is I want to pass `idUser`to another method in my controller it has strange value and basically it does not work. My second method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDetailsWeb", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginTimestampWeb(@RequestParam("idUser") String idUser, Model model) {
    // here i tired to acquired idUser and start a new template with it
    return "details"; // template displaying id
}
```

my User class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idUser", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("idUser")
    private Integer idUser;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("isAdmin")
    private boolean isAdmin;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("currentToken")
    private String currentToken;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("photo")
    private String photo;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String password, String currentToken, String photo) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.isAdmin = false;
        this.password = password;
        this.currentToken = currentToken;
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public Integer getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setId(Integer idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Boolean getAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(Boolean admin) {
        isAdmin = admin;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getCurrentToken() {
        return currentToken;
    }

    public void setCurrentToken(String currentToken) {
        this.currentToken = currentToken;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work. What kind of "strange value" do you get for "idUser"? Have you checked the source of the HTML page in the browser? Is it generated as expected (I mean the `option` values)?

Comment: @Cos64 Omg I'm stupid i had to change sth before posting it here and i did not check it, you are right now it is working as i wanted. Thanks for checking my code!